# Copying string to clipboard doesn't work (Java)

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

I'm trying to copy a string to the clipboard once user click on a proper button. This particular operation is supposed to be performed in a JDialog.

Here's part of my code, where the copying should occur:

```
btnCopy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(txtarContent.getText());
        Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

    }
});
```

*I'm using Eclipse (neon.3) on Mac OS X (10.12.4 Sierra).*

**Edit based on questions in comments:**

- No exception is thrown (nor are any errors/warnings)
- After an execution of the code, clipboard remains unmodified

Comment: Any exception thrown? Maybe `IllegalException` when invoking `setContents`?

Comment: I edited your post to keep the part causing troubles. Keep the bugged code to the minimum size possible (though your question was well asked, you don't have to post the parts that "can't cause problems because tested").

Comment: Also, what is the end result? Clipboard set to empty, bad copy, or no modifications?

Comment: No exceptions thrown. In the end, clipboard is the same as it was - with no modifications.
And thanks for the edit Nathan. That's my first question here and your tip is helpful. :)

Comment: @Immortalez, Post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. This way people can test the code to determine if the code is wrong or if it is a platform issue.

Comment: @camickr Interesting. I'm working at this demo example and I can't get this issue to occur. Copying this way works all the time. Should I add all my code then?

Comment: @Nathan Are you SURE that the cause is not the code you deleted? Like `txtarContent.getText()` being empty? I just wonder who approved that edit...

Comment: @Immortalez have you checked what `txtarContent.getText()` returns? like adding `System.out.println(txtarContent.getText())` before setting the clipboard - AND check that the listener is being executed !!

Comment: @Carlos Heuberger Although I was sure that txtarContent.getText() is never empty, I decided to check it. It turned out that the button doesnt react to being clicked, like there was something wrong with the listener. I tried recreating the listener but that didn't solve the problem. There's more. I tried creating another button and its listener doesn't work either.

Comment: @Immortalez, `Should I add all my code then?` - so you need to compare the working code with the code that is not working to see what the difference is. You have just demonstrated the problem is with your real code, not the API. So you need to isolate the problem before you can fix it.

Comment: I just recreated another JDialog with the same design and now everything seems to work. It turned out that the problem was with the button. It acted like there was no listener so the code wasn't even executed. Big thank you to everyone who tried to help. I really appreciate that. :)

Comment: In my case the text I wanted to copy to the clipboard was actually null. I will detect this and try to give user feedback whether text was copied or not.

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**
 The problem was not in the solution but in my code. 
It seems now that the button's listener wasn't working thus no code was executed. 

That's a good lesson for me as a beginner to check even the most obvious things, like whether the listener works or not. Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. But there's still a problem with your code. Your clipboard call should be this:

    clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);

StringSelection is both a Transferable and a ClipboardOwner, so it can respond correctly to changes in the clipboard contents.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I edited the question post in order not to mislead other beginners. I'll keep that in mind. :)